# The problem with running version managed Node as a remote SSH script

Tags: node.js, linux, ssh, nvm

My question is about `nvm` but it may relate to other Node version manages like `n` or `nvs`.

You probably a;ready know that you can run remote programs with SSH like this:

```
ssh user@server COMMAND
```

For example the command can be the Node.js script:

```
ssh user@devserver 'node ~/getstats'
```

The problem is that it will not work for Node that was installed using `nvm`. Why? Because `node` is actually an alias to something like `/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/bin/node`. The alias is installed in `~/.bashrc` which is run when you login with SSH. But when you execute remote command with `ssh SERVER COMMAND` environment scripts are not run because the shell runs in a restricted mode.

One work around is to create `~/node` which containts `/home/monitor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/bin/node *` and is executable, then you can do `ssh SERVER './node SCRIPT'`. But this is not perfect because once you upgrade Node the path will change and you will need to update this file as well.

What would be the recommended way to solve the problem with running version managed Node as a remote SSH script?

Comment: It should still use `~/.bashrc` according to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332533

Comment: @PatrickStephansen I think `.bashrc` is run but the environment variables are not set properly because the shell is in the restricted mode.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh user@devserver '. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && node ~/getstats'
```

Note that by default, `.bashrc` in Ubuntu 18.04 has the following:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: You saved me from (s)hell. I tried everything, except this. Can you tell what I have to do to execute the remote command with ssh just so that all the PATHs that are availabe when I ssh into the machine, are available, too? That is what I tried to achieve. It can't be so difficult, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run `sss user@host nvm run node ~/getstats` ?

Comment: I think you should be able to use this with the full path to `nvm` and maybe a `.nvmrc` file to specify which node version should be used for the particular script. The `.nvmrc` file can go in the same directory as the script. More details: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#nvmrc